# Journey Builder ContactEvents/Events API Call - Multiple records?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder

Any idea if the ContactEvents/Events REST API Calls support adding more than 1 contact record (JSON Array) to the request? I tried with the Events API but got the 'JSON Deserialization Exception'.